# Tiny Death Star bitizens menu

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

does anybody understand the order they put the bits in when you hit the star icon in bits menu? On TT it would mean dream jobs but in TDS it's in no order what so ever. I have 4 dream job bits and they are mixed up in the order.

Comment: I just looked at mine as well.. I cannot see how this is ordered.  Possible glitch?

Comment: Same. No logical ordering to it. Anyone have any info on this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a fuzzy memory, it looks like the bitizens are in order of when they moved in, with the latest arrivals at the bottom.